# eclipse: auto-generated method arg names

Tags: android, eclipse

auto generated method argument names looks like arg0, arg1, arg2 is there any way to have smart arg names like

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) 
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)

edit: My javadoc file seems missing, there are both android sdk and jdk are attached, i don't know googled but configuration of eclipse is a bit hard

edit: [eclipse android javadoc attachement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873319/eclipse-android-javadoc-attachement/6873805#6873805) solved my problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why eclipse is generating argument names as arg0,arg1,arg2.... for methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303943/why-eclipse-is-generating-argument-names-as-arg0-arg1-arg2-for-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the arguments are taken from the class files of the libraries. The names are optional and are normally only present in jars for debugging. Most probably your jars contain no debug information. Switch them with jars with debug information and you will get a much better support from eclipse.

**Edit:**
Optionally you can add source information to the jars for the same behaviour.