# eclipse android javadoc attachement

Tags: android, eclipse

My javadoc file seems missing, there are both android sdk and jdk are attached, i don't know googled but configuration of eclipse is a bit hard

I tried to attach javadoc but it cannot be validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already tried the following solution?

1. In eclipse, right click on your Android project and select Properties
2. On the menu on the left, select "Java Build Path"
3. On the right hand side, select the "tab" labelled "Libraries".
4. Here you should see the Android SDK that you're targeting. For example: "Android 2.2".
5. Click on the arrow to the left of the Android SDK to expand the sublevels.
6. Find "Android.jar" and click on the arrow to the left of that one as well to expand it.
7. You'll see a setting called "Javadoc location". Select that and then click on the "Edit" button.
8. At the top, RESELECT the path to your javadocs. This is usually "path_to_android_sdk/android-sdk-mac_86/docs/reference/". I say RESELECT because even if it's right, you should browse and do it over anyway.
9. Click on "validate". You should be all set now!

Mentioned [here](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2011/02/losing-javadocs-in-eclipse-solution.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728733/i-cant-see-android-sdk-javadoc-in-eclipse).