# Android Studio configure warnings and default fields names

Tags: android-studio

Recently I switched from ADT to Android Studio (latest version) and I have some questions *which I still couldn't answer after searching the IntelliJ help sites.*

1) How to turn off the "the field XYZ can be converted to a local variable" warning which is pretty annoying? I can decide those things by myself.

2) Is there a way to change the default variable names when overriding methods? Example: overriding the `getView()` method of a `BaseAdapter` gives me

```
 public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
```

and I want it to be

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

for convenience. Same applies to other methods in other classes.

Comment: You can disable the warnings in the settings in the lint section. That part with the variable renaming is confusing, I don't have this problem. Did you download the source code of the Android SDK?

Comment: nope I didn't download those, but I didn't in Eclipse/ADT either, and Eclipse was always generating proper variable names when overriding methods

Comment: Have you tried to apply similar techniques that apply to [Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303943/why-eclipse-is-generating-argument-names-as-arg0-arg1-arg2-for-methods) in this regard? It seems that it's auto-gen-ing them. I've had this issue in Eclipse from time to time but even worse is they auto-gen names like `arg0`, so I guess you should consider yourself lucky.

Comment: well, I will try to download the source and check if this helps

Comment: Before you do check this -> select the method and press `ctrl+q`/`F1`(Win/Mac). When I do I follow the method to the Adapter interface link which shows the proper names. So at least in my case AS has the ability to give them but doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress warnings. Posting my answer will not be allowed so please see explanation on how to suppress warnings using

```
@SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
```

in my answer to the following question, meaning I have to mark this as a duplicate question even though no one had ever given a solution to this before which is why people like you kept asking the same question over and over again which is to me, understandable:

["Field can be converted to a local variable" message appearing when setting action bar colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713073/field-can-be-converted-to-a-local-variable-message-appearing-when-setting-acti/39706506#39706506)

Comment: ahm.. thanks for the late answer mate. Regarding the duplicate: as you can see my question goes back to 23 Aug. 2014 and your linked question is dated 29 Jul. 2015 ;)