# "Field can be converted to a local variable" message appearing when setting Android ActionBar colour

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

After setting the colour of the Action Bar, `actionBarColor` in `private String actionBarColor = "#B36305";` gets highlighted yellow and a warning is returned for some reason. What can be done to get rid of this warning?

> Field can be converted to a local variable

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String actionBarColor = "#B36305";

    private int getFactorColor(int color, float factor) {
        float[] hsv = new float[3];
        Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
        hsv[2] *= factor;
        color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionBarColor)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the significance of this warning? I mean how problematic can it be from performance or memory use aspect , if left unhandled..?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

What the warning is telling you is that `actionBarColor` shouldn't be a global variable (i.e. a field), because it's only used in one method (`onCreate`). This is good advice: you should always minimize the scope of your variables, because it improves readability and reduces possibilities for programming errors.

To get rid of the warning, fix the problem by declaring the variable within `onCreate`:

```
final String actionBarColor = "#B36305";

if(actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(
        new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(actionBarColor)));
}
```

Comment: How about constants? I like to declare them at the top of my class.

Comment: @Trace, yes, you can declare them on the class-level (`private|public static final String`), and doing so you shouldn't see this warning.

Comment: I still get the warning. I'll just ignore it for this use case thanks.

Comment: @html_programmer I got the warning because I forgot the `static`. Adding it removed the warning.

Answer (score 85):

If you know you will use the variable(s), add to the top of your class:

`@SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")`

Comment: this is what i needed. I have a field. it _could_ have been converted to a local variable, but it was used inside of a loop and i didn't want to re-initialize it over and over every time the loop executed

Comment: Just a note, this is often needed if your field is added to an object that manages its containees using weak references. If you convert to a local variable it will be garbage collected.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Readability is *better* when magic numbers and strings are declared at the top of the class, and `private static` makes them constants which is even clearer.

Comment: THANK YOU !!! (so much!) in mine I needed it later in some self reflection

Comment: I came for that explicitly!

Answer (score -1):

This is not a error this is waring when you go in the lint errors than it will show in class level variable which used as a local variable. Go and just define it as a local variable. It will Works

For example -

```
private Tracker mTracker, mTracker2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GoogleAnalytics mInstance = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    mTracker = mInstance.getDefaultTracker();
    mTracker2 = mInstance.getTracker(URL.ANALYTIC);
    mInstance.setDefaultTracker(mTracker2);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.actress_about_detail);
}
```

we use mtracker variable as a local so we have to declare in oncreate method. This will resolve your error.

Hope this will help you.