# 'Field can be converted to a local variable' message, and then variables not recognised

Tags: android, variables

I was getting this message, 'Field can be converted to a local variable'. Did some research on it and found this good post:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713073/field-can-be-converted-to-a-local-variable-message-appearing-when-setting-acti)

The variables I was getting the message with are these, declared straight after:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final ListView listview;
final String callType;
final String phoneNumber;
final String callDate;
final String callDuration;
final Date callDateTime;
```

So I took it's advice and made my code like this:

```
package com.example.chris.sunil_gupta;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    private List <CallData>list = new ArrayList<CallData>();
    private Context context=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final ListView listview;
        final String callType;
        final String phoneNumber;
        final String callDate;
        final String callDuration;
        final Date callDateTime;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        context=this;

        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView_CallData);

        getCallDetails();
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void getCallDetails()
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);

        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);


        while (managedCursor.moveToNext())
        {

            phoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);

            callDateTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));

            callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);

            String cType = null;

            int cTypeCode = Integer.parseInt(callType);

            switch(cTypeCode)
            {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    cType = "OUTGOING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    cType= "INCOMING";
                    break;

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    cType = "MISSED";
                    break;
            }

            CallData calldata=new CallData(cType, phoneNumber, callDateTime, callDuration);
            list.add(calldata);
        }

        managedCursor.close();
    }
}
```

And now callType, phoneNumber, callDate, callDuration, callDateTime are coming up in red and I get errors - illegal start of expression - when I try compile my project.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and how to fix this problem?

Comment: You need to declare your variables in the method that uses them (getCallDetails).

Comment: Put this as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now getting errors because you've declared your variables in the wrong method. Move the declarations from onCreate into getCallDetails where they are being used.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `final` modifier.

When applied to an instance variable, the final modifier simply means that the instance variable can’t be changed.

In your example you declared final variables, but didn't set them any value. That's the reason of your issue.

Also you should declare your variables in that methods where you use them. So parts of your code should be like these:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // ...
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_CallData);
    // ...
}

public void getCallDetails() {
    // ...
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {

    final String phoneNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
    final String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
    final String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
    final Date callDateTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
    final String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy, I think it's more sense to not declare my variables 'final', as you said, but final or not, the errors were still happening. I think the problem was not declaring variables in the right method. +1 though.

Comment: @ChristopheHarris. In your methods you can declare vars final just to show you are not going to reassign their values. It's just for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Because your variables are final. You cannot reassign any value to a final variable. Remove the keyword final and try it again. Let me know if it works or not. Good luck.

Comment: Cheers, but it looks like specifically the problem was not declaring variables in the right method.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to be final then make it as static

Answer (score -3):

I don't think you can declare variables before the call to super.onCreate() because you have no Context.

Comment: Nope. We can declare before `onCreate()` being called.